# notsupported coinbase createorder() is not supported yet

Tags: node.js, ccxt

Using node.js with ccxt libraries I have API to coinbase and it's getting webhook json from tradingview. While I have node properly getting data from web services and connecting API to coinbase to retrieve balances and calculating trade, there is an error each time creating order using ccxt's exchange.js. error: "notsupported coinbase createorder() is not supported yet."

I'm trying to trade BTC/USD pairs. On coinbase API setting i have all permissions enabled. Perhaps my webhook is not setup properly. I'm not sure. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trading on coinbase is only recently available using coinbases "Advanced Trading" for which there is no api yet; therefore, there's no `createOrder` method for coinbase. There is a CCXT `coinbasepro` class if you would like to use Coinbase Pro.

Comment: Is there a way to write my own createOrder to use on Coinbase? Or is that just not going to work unless I use Coinbase pro?

Comment: @AlSol coinbase hasn't created a way to connect to their servers, so no, unless you wrote something really hacky that tried to use the html website and tried to look like it human using a web browser (don't do this)

Comment: Copy that.......

Answer (score 0):

Coinbase has an API for Advanced Trading now.   Ref:  https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/advanced-trade-api/docs/rest-api-overview.

However, I don't know whether ccxt supports it yet - I can't find any ccxt release notes.   However, I did find the following issue on the ccxt github page that seems to be a request for support:  https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/issues/16281

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The issue above has been resolved, and ccxt now supports Coinbase Advanced Trading.